# Why does Robocopy skip a changed file if file length and file date are the same?

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, robocopy

I've been using Robocopy for a while to create a (quick) backup of my disks. The exact command I use is `robocopy /MIR /R:0 sourcedrive:\ targetdrive:\sourcedrivename` .

This should create an exact mirror of all my files in a backup location, which for almost all files is the case.

Unfortunately I noticed that there is one large file which never gets copied since it's creation, despite the file being altered on several occasions. It's a 200Gb container, but neither the size of the container nor the OS date for the container ever get updated.

Why does Robocopy not update this file in the backup destination, and, more important, how can I get Robocopy to check and copy the file?

When I do an rsync from my backup destination to the next backup destination, rsync does pick up these changes.

I've found countless other posts, but none of them take into account that neither size nor date change for the file, therefor I created a new question.

Thanks.

Comment: If the file changed the "modified date" should also have been changed thus getting the file to be copied...

Comment: @Ricaardo Bohner That's why I explicitly stated that the modified date didn't change. Updating the container file never changes the modified date (only the contents of the file change, never the size nor date).

Comment: does the archive attribute get set?

Comment: @Jasen If I clear the attribute with Attrib -A <filename> and add or delete some files inside the container file, the archive attribute is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robocopy is a utility build with speed in mind. It will only check for filesize or date modified in order to detect change. If it were to do an md5 check on every file, the copier would be a lot slower.

Robocopy does not support this however.

This will lead you with a few options.

1. If you use a script, and robocopy is part of that script, make it delete that file before the copy starts so Robocopy will copy a new version to it.
2. Use another tool, such as TeraCopy that can do an MD5 comparison
3. Make sure the modified date is changed periodically. This can be done using powershell.

From personal experience my preference would be number 2, but it is up to you what you want. This answer is just to provide you with alternatives, given that Robocopy itself just does not support md5 comparisons and thus can't possibly find out if the file has changed by what was given to it. So either make enough changes to the environment such that robocopy will understand it, or use a different tool that does not need the environment to be changed for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand RoboCopy would work a lot slower if it had to check each and every file completely. I'll have a look at TeraCopy, but at first glance it's not a command line utility, so I won't be able to use it I'm afraid. As it only happens with one particular file, I'll just copy that file each and every backup, it's always limited to 200Gb so it won't slow down my backup.

Comment: You may want to check out Free File Sync. You use the GUI to setup the sync, but you can run the sync itself from commandline. I use that tool to setup a non-destructive backup against randsom infections. Every time it deletes a file in my backup because its gone in the source, or it replaces a file, it moves the old file to a deleted files folder. By the use of a script, I clear those deleted files after a certain elapsed time. It does compare files to more than size and date change.

Comment: Now that would be very useful for me! Thanks for the suggestion, I'll be sure to check it out. The delayed delete is also a feature which could be useful.

Comment: Keep in mind, Free File Sync is donation ware. Its entirely free, but its limited in speed as you can only have 2 syncrhonous connections to a file at a time. You can donate 1$ to get that donation version and use that version for a lifetime and never update, or maybe every blue moon get an update for 1$. You can only use the donation version on 3 installs though and it will not activate on the 4th, but for 1$ that is a steal anyway. I have it set to 20 connections to get a very speedy copy. :)